# Why getline() throws 'std::ios_base::failure' when exception mask is not set to eofbit?

Tags: c++, exception, getline

Consider the following code:

```
    ifstream in;
    try {
        in.exceptions ( ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit );
        in.open(pConfLocation);
    } catch ( ifstream::failure e ) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't open configuration file\n");
    }

    vector<string> lns;
    string s;

    in.clear();
    while ( !in.eof() ){
        getline( in, s );
        boost::algorithm::trim(s);
        lns.push_back( s+='\n');
    }
```

So:

1. I set the following "exception mask" ( ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit ) for the needs of the try-catch block. The file opens without problems.
2. In while{} block, I know that at the end of the file eofbit will be set. [But](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/)

> The exception mask is an internal value of all stream objects
>   specifying which state flags have to throw an exception **when they are
>   set**.

I did NOT set *ifstream::eofbit*, but anyway the following error appears at runtime:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
  what():  basic_ios::clear
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

I cannot understand this behavior. I tried to use *in.clear()* right before *while{}* but with no effect. clear() itself sets *goodbit*, and as far as I understand, "flags have to throw an exception" (see the quote above), but when *googbit* set it's not causing to throw any exceptions…

If to delete

```
        in.exceptions ( ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit );
```

it works.

---

**How to make getline() work in this case?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in your input iteration. `eofbit` is only set when the last read reached EOF, not if the next read will read only EOF. When the latter happens, `failbit` is set at the same time. See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

In your particular case, if the file ends with a newline (as it probably does), the `getline()` reads up to and including that newline and returns. `eofbit` is still not set. The next `getline()` then encounters EOF directly, and as per its documentation, "If the function extracts no elements, it calls `setstate(failbit)`."

Comment: Ok, but I clear()-ed exception mask, why is it still seems to be active?

Comment: @Razorfever There is no `clean()` member, I assume you meant `clear()`. This clears the state bits (`eofbit`, `failbit` and `badbit`), but does not affect the exception mask.

Comment: Yes, I used clear() sorry [fixed in Q]. Probably the last one question related to the problem: is there any way to return to state preceding setting of the exception mask?

Comment: @Razorfever I don't understand what you mean now. Do you want to clear the exception mask? If so, you can do `in.exceptions(ifstream::goodbit);`

Comment: I mean I dont understand why if to remove "in.exceptions ( ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit )" there will be no errors visible errors in this code.

Comment: If the exception is not thrown, the last `getline()` (the one which sets `failbit`) will clear `s` and you'll process an empty string (push `"\n"` into `lns`) which was never part of the input. In other words, you're getting bogus data.

Comment: It is worth mentioning the correct loop form to use: `while (getline( in, s )) {
        boost::algorithm::trim(s);
        lns.push_back( s+='\n');
    }`

Comment: I met the same problem. I don't quite get how you guys solve the problem while keeping exceptions flags set for `try/catch` block.

Comment: @LingboTang You have to have a clear idea of what is "reaching EOF" and what is "failure" in stream terminology (I suggest reading some [`iostate` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate)). If you really want exceptions for failure but not for reading past the last line in a file, you have to use `peek` before reading.